# In the movie "Equals", are conception summons obligatory?

Tags: equals

What if the woman doesn't want to have children? Could she refuse or would she still have to be impregnated?

Comment: Would she want to refuse?  On a separate not even if there are consequences to an action that action could still be performed.  Do not believe this is addressed in the movie though.